# Set timeout arrow functions

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Im working on some mocha tests and I was asked to refactor my code in which they ask me to use arrow functions.

But now I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

This also happened when before the refactor but to solve it I used: `this.timeout(1000)` but now this doesn't work with arrow functions. How could I set a timeout higher than 2000ms ? Below Is my test.

```
describe('Test', () => {
  token = 'un_assigned';
  before( (done) => {
    getToken('random_token', (response) => {
      token = response.token;
      fs.writeFileSync('./tests/e2e/helpers/token.json', JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      done();
    })
  });

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    it('Comparando file ' + file, (done) => {
      const id = file.split('./screenshots/')[1];
      compare(file, id, token, function (response) {
        expect(response.TestPassed).to.be.true;
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The code works for me as it is. Seems like internet problem, just try again later.

Comment: *"I was asked to refactor my code in which they ask me to use arrow functions."* Just for the sake of using arrow functions? that sounds... misguided. incorrect. dangerous. Arrow functions aren't a replacement for normal functions. They're simply for a different purpose.

Comment: Arrow functions has a major disadvantage of not having "this" for each function(). It's only recommended if you want to to write a one statement in a function just to save few lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test context isn't being bound when using arrow functions. So you can't use `this.timeout`.

But you can set timeout on specific test cases this way:

```
it('Comparando file ' + file, (done) => {
  ...
}).timeout(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, and fixed it by converting my function to this format:

```
it('should do the test', done => {

    ...

    done();
}.timeout(15000);
```

The error only went away after I included **both** the `done()` and the `timeout(15000)` (course, the 15000 can be any number longer than the program runtime).

Note that although this quick fix worked for me because I'm not bothered by slowness, as a general rule it's bad coding practice to fix errors like this by extending timeout, rather the program speed should be improved.